# 'R' is in the default package android error

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I'm using Android Studio in order to learn, all my projects work correctly, bust when I go inside some Java class of android studio (for example the *ListView* class), I see that there are 590 errors.

Screenshot of *ListView.java* class

[image: Screenshot of _ListView.java_ class].

When I look into the *R* error a message is shown: *Class 'R' is in the default package*. [Screenshot of the *Class 'R' is in the default package* message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bRlta.png)

For the other imports the message shown is this: *Cannot resolve symbol 'ViewRootImpl*

Screenshot of the *Cannot resolve symbol 'ViewRootImpl* message

[image: Screenshot of the _Cannot resolve symbol 'ViewRootImpl_ message]

And this problem happens to all the java classes.

[image: TextView class]

I've already tried to Sync the project with grade files, cleaning and rebuilding the project, but nothing was useful. I tried to create news projects, but the problem still there.

My question is why all those errors mean and why my projects dosen't seen affected.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't have to care about these errors since you are not compiling the code. It's part of the SDK.

Platform components have references to platform internals that are not part of the public SDK. That's why there are errors.

When compiling your own code, you're using prebuilt platform code in the SDK.

Answer (score 2):

Close Project and reopen from directory not from open recent option
or
Clean Project from build menu and rebuild it

Comment: Thanks. This fixed it.